# RabbitMQ is not connecting Access Refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a queue in Rabbit but I'm dealing with connection issues.
My application.properties is as follow:

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=xxxxxxx.xxxx.dev.xxx:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=people-consumer
spring.rabbitmq.password=*******
peopleevents.vhost=PEOPLE
peopleevents.queue=qu-people-cores-update
peopleevents.exchange=ex-people-updates
peopleevents.routingkey=ONLINE.UPDATE.PERSONF.PERSONF;
```

But when attempting to connect is fails in the address as you can see here:

```
2022-06-27 14:06:43.542  INFO 13668 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-06-27 14:06:43.544  INFO 13668 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [SCGLCCRAMQD0005.SCGER.DEV.CORP:5672]
2022-06-27 14:06:43.958  INFO 13668 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: connectionFactory#63538bb4:0/SimpleConnection@8b13d91 [delegate=amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE, localPort= 59226]
2022-06-27 14:06:44.236 ERROR 13668 --- [.2.164.186:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'qu-people-cores-update' in vhost 'PEOPLE' refused for user 'people-consumer', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
ACCESS_REFUSED
```

means that the user `people-consumer` doesn't have the grants to access to `qu-people-cores-update` in vhost `PEOPLE`

Check the user grant on the management UI: http://localhost:15672/#/users/people-consumer

or using the `rabbitmqctl` tool